# Getting a div's "scrollWidth" when it has an absolute positioned child-div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem getting the width of a div's content (of the content, not the div itself).

The usual approach would be Javascript's `scrollWidth` property, I think.

The problem: within this div, another div is positioned absolute and has a negative `right` value (-350px). I can't change this (it's a menu, sliding in when you click a button, overlapping other elements. It needs to be positioned like that).

The `scrollWidth` returns the width of the outer div's content PLUS the negative right-value (in Chrome, didn't test other browsers).

Here's a short example:

```
/* ... */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R4Cs5/12/

But I need the content's width that is accessible by scrollbars.

Any ideas?

Please use Jquery, no plain Javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why jQuery and not plain Javascript, if it's possible to do it with just the latter?

Comment: I dont relly know any more how Javascript works, as I'm almost only using Jquery ;D
But of course you're right, if it's easy to do with Javascript, then lets do it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your jsfiddle doesn't import any jQuery library, while you wanted to use it. Anyway, with jQuery you can use `.width` to get an element's width see here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arsyadtaufan/aJRMr/1/).

Comment: Exactly, I have done that billions of times before :)

But I'm searching for a way to get the content's with, not the div's width (when the content overflows the div).

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your question. So the content is a children of `div#test`? How about selecting all children of `div#test` except the menu `div`? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arsyadtaufan/U5Tb2/1/)